# Installing node.js with express module

Tags: node.js, express

I'm on latest stable debian
I am able to do `apt-get install nodejs` but cannot install npm with apt, so I compiled from `wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.16/node-v0.8.16.tar.gz` and everything looks good.

Now I want to install the express module globally and did `sudo npm install -g express`

but I get this warning:

```
npm WARN engine express@4.11.1: wanted: {"node":">= 0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"v0.8.16","npm":"1.1.69"})
```

then typing `express` in the commandline says command not found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the error message, it looks like you've installed an older version of Node ?

Comment: You need to do `apt-get purge nodejs` and then recompile node's source

Comment: ohh i think i did... Which one do I use from here: http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/  I'm on debian64bit so this: node-v0.10.36-linux-x64.tar.gz ?

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash I ran that command and also apt-get remove nodejs however I can still use npm in the command line, how do I get rid of it so I can recompile? I removing the /bin entry good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on the old version. 
I needed to get the latest one from here:

http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v0.10.36.tar.gz

Then running the commands after untaring

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then `npm install -g express`